# tika-app-2.9.0. incompatibility with xmlbeans-5.0.3

Tags: apache-poi, apache-tika, xmlbeans

We are are trying to upgrade tika-app-2.3.0.jar to tika-app-2.9.0.jar and this is used for extension detection of uploaded files.
We have following dependencies as well in our application,
poi.5.2.1.jar which requires xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar
Any pointers will be appreciated.

Application is failing while detecting .docx file extension with below exception:
Exception in thread "pool-13-thread-2" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlCursor.close()V (loaded from file:/home/user/jars/xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b1430077) called from class org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.XWPFWordExtractorDecorator (loaded from file:/home/user/libs/tika-app-2.9.0.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b1430077).
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.XWPFWordExtractorDecorator.processEmbeddedObjects(XWPFWordExtractorDecorator.java:339)
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.XWPFWordExtractorDecorator.extractParagraph(XWPFWordExtractorDecorator.java:231)
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.XWPFWordExtractorDecorator.extractIBodyText(XWPFWordExtractorDecorator.java:170)
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.XWPFWordExtractorDecorator.buildXHTML(XWPFWordExtractorDecorator.java:138)
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.AbstractOOXMLExtractor.getXHTML(AbstractOOXMLExtractor.java:139)
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLExtractorFactory.parse(OOXMLExtractorFactory.java:247)
at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser.parse(OOXMLParser.java:115)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298)
at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:203)
at com.test.common.AbstractFolderImpl.extractMetadata(AbstractFolderImpl.java:103)
at com.test.impl.providers.JackrabbitFolderImpl.createAsset(JackrabbitFolderImpl.java:203)
at com.test.bulkupload.impl.RepoHandler.createAssets(RepoHandler.java:118)
at com.test.bulkupload.impl.FileConsumer.processBatch(FileConsumer.java:152)
at com.test.bulkupload.impl.FileConsumer.run(FileConsumer.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)

Comment: XmlCursor close was only added in XMLBean 5.1.0. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-582

Comment: Make sure you use the version of Apache POI that ships with Apache Tika, don't try and mix-n-match dependency versions!

Comment: @gagravarr , I have verified the tika-app-2.9.0.jar for versions of POI or xmlbeans jar version but could not find any details . May I know how to find?

Comment: The `tika-app` jar is a standalone jar with all dependencies embedded in it, intended to be run from the command line etc. If you're including Tika in a Java project, just add the Tika dependencies to your maven/gradle build